# How to add ellipse center in ggbiplot?

Tags: r, ellipse, ggbiplot

I have data set seperated in 4 groups: groups = taxabylevel.
I ran ggbiplot and add ellipses around each group. 
How to add centre of each ellipses?

```
g <- ggbiplot(pca, obs.scale = 1, var.scale = 1, alpha=0, groups = taxaBylevel,show_guide = FALSE, ellipse = TRUE)
print(g)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data(iris)

pca<-prcomp(iris[,1:4],scale=T)


g<-ggbiplot(pca, obs.scale = 1, var.scale = 1, alpha=0, groups = iris[,5],show_guide = FALSE, ellipse = TRUE)


gmean=aggregate(g$data[,1:2],list(group=g$data$group),mean)

ggbiplot(pca, obs.scale = 1, var.scale = 1, alpha=0, groups = iris[,5],show_guide = FALSE, ellipse = TRUE)+
  geom_point(data=gmean,aes(group=group,colour=group))
```

[image]